# Return a result from a database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use this method to return a boolean value based on whether or not the custody already exists in the database.

```
var custody = db.Custodies.LastOrDefault(c => c.studentId == id);
if (db.Custodies.Contains(custody) && custody.custodyEndTime == null)
{
    return true;
}
    return false;
}
```

The Custodies table uses a composite primary key but I only want to search by studentId, so I can't use Find(). I want to find the custody entry based on the studentId to check if that student is currently in a custody with no custodyEndTime.

I tried using a linq query but that gave me an anonymous type and it complained about that too.

Any help would be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. `any()` will give you true value if any record found with studentid else return false

```
return db.Custodies.Where(c => c.studentId == id && c.custodyEndTime == null).Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine whether any element in the collection satisfies given condition or not:

```
bool exists = db.Custodies.Any(c => c.studentId == id && c.custodyEndTime == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Any` method for this.

```
bool custodyExists = db.Custodies.Any(c => c.studentId == id && c.custodyEndTime == null);
```

Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

For more LINQ samples have a look at [101 LINQ-Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). Most of them are working with LING to SQL very well.